# TYPO3 override heading based on frame

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have added a frame 101 by Page TS Config, and when the user chooses this frame I would like to set a specific heading wrap in setup to override css-styled-content.

From my understanding I should be doing something like this:

```
temp.header < lib.stdheader.10
lib.stdheader.10 >
lib.stdheader.10 = CASE
lib.stdheader.10 {
  key.field = section_frame
  default < temp.header
  101 = TEXT
  101 {
    current = 1
    datawrap = <h4 class="myheading">|</h4>
  }
}
```

But this is not currently working as expected. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In TYPO3 7 and above its much more easy with fluid_styled_content. In css_styled_content you should check the construction of lib.stdHeader exacly in the Object Browser. I guess its already depending on some other constants of css_styled_content so just check the source construct of lib.stdHeader to find the right placement for your 101 wrap.